# What do I do here?

Tags: user-interface, app-shortcuts, input

This looks like I'm being prompted for a file NAME. Instead I get a window showing file system STRUCTURE.

I know it's simple. Should have a simple answer. For instance I need to export a file. I get a window showing subdirectories structure but no input window. And, worst of all, no universal help screen to prompt me. Or at least nothing I easily see.

Can someone try this and tell me what I missed ?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking about. Export a file from where? Which app or window are you in? What did you select to get here? Please explain. You may also wish to create a screenshot, post it at https://imgur.com or some other open image hosting site, then come back here, click [edit], and add the weblink to that image to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are there filename field in left bottom corner?

Look at this: https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-rCFcnJdcem0/XiVGvEss0WI/AAAAAAAAZxc/mGDt9qNUitUn2AHrs5Zhap_8Mon17D1IQCK4BGAYYCw/s1600/save-open.png

Comment: Thanks but no. Nothing to prompt me.

Comment: To clarify for everyone answering. The screenshots I posted can't make it more clear. Total text I'm describing howa reusable UI component is being used WITHOUT a prompt. Using the rules of UI desigbn for a drunk user, if you tried the steps you would see teh problem exactly. I did solve it, I installed UBUNTU. Same exact steps in same programs displayed an action and choose prompt that's absent in this variant. For the reasons of lack of response, vagueness and real UI issues I'll probably never come back.

Comment: @JamesWalker But you did **not** post any screenshot 